# When run test, TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'travelDatas' of '(0 , _GetTravelDatas.getTravelDatas)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

When I run test, it show **TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'travelDatas' of '(0 , _GetTravelDatas.getTravelDatas)(...)' as it is undefined.**

As you see the screenshot: [unit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU9fb.png)

There isn't any console error or warning.

Could anyone help please

**travelListTest.spec.js**

```
import { mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import TravelList from '../../src/components/TravelList.vue'
import { getTravelDatas } from '../../src/composables/GetTravelDatas'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'

const wrapper = shallowMount(TravelList, {
  global: {
      plugins: [ElementPlus]
  }
})

jest.mock('../../src/composables/GetTravelDatas')

describe('TravelList Test', () => {
      test('click more will call GoToTravelDetailPage', () => {
        wrapper.vm.GoToTravelDetailPage = jest.fn()
        console.log(wrapper.html())
        wrapper.find('.el-button').trigger('click')
        expect(wrapper.vm.GoToTravelDetailPage).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
})
```

**TravelList.vue**

```
.....
<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity';
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { getTravelDatas } from '../composables/GetTravelDatas'
export default {
  name: 'TravelList',
  setup() {
    
    const { travelDatas } = getTravelDatas();
    const router = useRouter();

    function GoToTravelDetailPage(acctractionId) {
      router.push({ path: `/travelDetail/${acctractionId}` })
    }

    
    return { travelDatas, GoToTravelDetailPage };
  },
};
</script>
```

**GetTravelDatas.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from '@vue/runtime-core';

export function getTravelDatas() {
    const travelDatas = ref([])
        axios.get('https://localhost:5001/MyTravel/GetTravelData')
        .then((response) => {
        if (!response.data.success) {
            alert(response.data.errorMessage)
        }else{
            travelDatas.value = response.data.travelDetail
        }
        }).catch((error) => {
        alert('Unexpected Error: ', error.message)
        console.log(error)
        });
    return { travelDatas }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking the `GetTravelDatas` module with an auto-mock version by calling:

```
jest.mock('../../src/composables/GetTravelDatas')
```

That means that all the methods exported from that module will be mocked (the real code of the method will not be called) and the mocked version will return *undefined* when called.

In the code you are testing you then have:

```
const { travelDatas } = getTravelDatas();
```

Reading the `travelDatas` property from *undefined* is causing the error you are seeing.

You should mock the `getTravelDatas` method so that it returns the appropriate data. For example, returning an empty array would look like:

```
getTravelDatas.mockReturnValue([]);
```